# Can't load a List of object (<Item>) to firebase realtime database

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a 2D game app using unity c#.

I have a list of item(object) and each item contains double Price, double Multiplier and int Level.

I'm trying to load that List to the FireBase Realtime DataBase using json inorder to save the player's peronal shop.
to try and make it look like this in the DB:

[image: DB should be like this]

**This is my Item class:**

```
public class Item
{
    
    public double Price {get; set;}
    public double Multiplier { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    

    public Item(double price, double multiplier, int level)
    {
        this.Price = price;
        this.Multiplier = multiplier;
        this.Level = level;
    }
}
```

**And this is my Shop class:**

```
public class Shop
{
    public List<Item> ShopList { get; set; }

    public Shop()
    {
        this.ShopList = new List<Item>();
    }

    public void InitShop()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets\Scripts\Data\ShopData.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(',');
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(words[0]);
            double mul = Convert.ToDouble(words[1]);
            int level = Convert.ToInt32(words[2]);
            Item i = new Item(price, mul, level);
            this.ShopList.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna use Json to create your save system, you might aswell use the provided **JsonUtitlity** by **Unity**. With this you can **automatically** create a save data object in the json format and save that.

**API Reference:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html

**Youtube Tutorial (Code Monkey):** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uMFEM-napE

If you don't mind using a third party dll, you might want to check out **Newtonsoft**
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: I found the JsonUtitlity  breaks down when working the `object` type. It doesn't convert it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NewtonSoft /Json.Net for Unity. Pakcage can be found here:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

Works like this:

```
string ConvertToJson(object obj) 
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}

string ConvertFromJson<T>(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}


void Usage() 
{
    List<object> myList = populateListWithSomeData();
    
    // Save it
    var json = ConvertToJson(myList);
    SaveInDatabase(json);
    
    // Load it
    var json = LoadFromDatabase();
    myList = ConvertFromJson<List<object>>(json);
}
```

Comment: first, there is no thing "Serialize" and "Deserialize" and this line ```return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);``` dont work, it write that it cant convert <T> to string

Comment: `T` in programming is a generic term. It means you put in whatever you want out. If you want a string out then write: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json). Which should be redundant because json is already a stirng. Here is the documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you read from realtime db to Unity, it keeps the type data as keywords which is problematic to `JSON.parse()`
these are most likely causing issues for your code, there is a JSON.parser that handles this, at the current time I am unable to find the script in mind.

an alternative from the community is to convert it to a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
{
    dict.Add(child.Key, child.Value);
}
```